# linebreak from text_area missing in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, line-breaks

I use a text_area in my test rails app

```
= form_for @post do |f|
  = f.text_field :title, size: '40'
  = f.text_area :description, size: "80x20"
```

and render markdown using RedCarpet

```
.post-description
  = markdown(post.description)
```

When I insert a list into the text_area, markdown is not rendered correctly due to missing line breaks in the description field.

The result is something like this

```
=markdown("1. test 2. test")
```

I guess linebreaks from the form need to be saved in the database. A simple string with a linebreak

```
=markdown("1. test /n 2. test")
```

worked as expected.

Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

normally the `textarea` field have newline saved as `\r\n`, and it can be parse by the `redcarpet`. you need to check the `post.description` output, check if there exist some jquery plugin for the description edit, if there are callback which modify the `description`.Find the reason why `description` field it didn't have newline.

try

```
require 'redcarpet'

markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML.new)

p markdown.render("1. test 2. test")
p markdown.render("1. eee\r\n2. 113")
```

Comment: In the end I have found double line breaks (\r\n\r\n) in the description field.

Comment: Finally found the real cause. li and ul css styles changed the lists. Your answer is correct and my code is now working without any gsub. Sorry for the confusion.